# Bluetooth dongle - not pairing

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, dongle

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed a bluetooth dongle. It has detected the other device - a speaker - but will not pair with it. 
Can you help? Thanks. HJO

Comment: Edit - laptop has now  asked me to enter a pin into the speaker... i fear i have reached an impasse.